# check if values for a variable in one dataframe appear in another dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have two dfs that sampled the same group at different time points, with some attrition and some addition/omission of variables across timepoints. (code to generate sample data at the bottom)

I want to calculate the attrition rate between waves based on whether ids (a chr variable) from df1 also appear in df2 and create a binary column in df1 indicating whether or not ids appear in df2.

both df1 and df2 are formatted as below

```
id                         var_1  var_2 ...
    
5ea1954758634f04542a50bf    5      1
3fjkfgho55efy467grtu523r    7      4
df79756gh5485trhfsdkig3d    3      8
```

my desired output is:

```
df1

id                         in _df2  var_1  var_2 ...
    
5ea1954758634f04542a50bf   Yes       5      1
3fjkfgho55efy467grtu523r   Yes       4      2
df79756gh5485trhfsdkig3d   No        8      3
```

I have tried using this code but it does not seem to work (there is no column generated in df1):

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(in_df2 = c("no", "yes")[1 + (rowSums(
    outer(
      strsplit(id, "\\s+"),
      strsplit(df2$id, "\\s+"),
      Vectorize(function(x, y) all(x %in% y) | all(y %in% x))
    )
  ) > 0)])
```

code to generate sample dfs:

```
#df1
df1 <- structure(list(id = c("5ea1954758634f04542a50bf", "3fjkfgho55efy467grtu523r", "df79756gh5485trhfsdkig3d", 
"d6rg756ghuej4678dfdkig3d", "546dt547546hgdvc842a50bf"), var1 = 1:5, var2 = 3:7), row.names = c(
-6L), class = "data.frame")

#df2
df2 <- structure(list(id = c("73egdv4758634f04542a50bf", "3fjkfgho55efy467grtu523r", "tr54756gh5485trhfsdkig3d", 
"d6rg756ghuej4678dfdkig3d", "357dt547546hgdvc842a50bf"), var1 = 2:7, var4 = 3:7), row.names = c(
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Using your `dput` you could simply use `intersect(df1, df2)` (or `intersect(df1$id, df2$id)`) to subset `df1` with those values contained in `df2`, but your dput doesnt include any `var_x` columns or values. Could you edit your question to include a more complete `dput` and also desired output? Good luck!

Comment: thanks! I realise the samples were sparse, its a very large dataset so I (over) simplified for ease. I've edited my question to be a bit clearer

Comment: Thanks for editing! Both your dputs are returning warnings since you have differing row lengths for different columns (ie, there are only 5 IDs in each data frame, but 6 values in `df1$var2` (length(3:8) == 6) and similar for `df2` for both var columns. Could you tweak these data to be properly formatted? Thanks!

Comment: also, could you explain how you got the differences in `var1` and `var2` in your desired output? It would be best if your `dput` data matched the sample and desired data you put in the demonstration. This remains too unclear to provide an accurate answer

Comment: I can't seem to edit the issues with your `dput` output.

Comment: Can you clarify, are you expecting that *only* ID matches? Or do you require all of ID, var1, var2 match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need to do is check on the `id` column you can simply do:

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 |>
  mutate(in_df2 = ifelse(id %in% df2$id, "Yes", "No"))
#                         id var1 var2 in_df2
# 1 5ea1954758634f04542a50bf    1    3     No
# 2 3fjkfgho55efy467grtu523r    2    4    Yes
# 3 df79756gh5485trhfsdkig3d    3    5     No
# 4 d6rg756ghuej4678dfdkig3d    4    6    Yes
# 5 546dt547546hgdvc842a50bf    5    7     No
```

Here is another option using `semi_join` which is a type of filter join you can use to subset common rows. This will allow for more merge keys than just `id`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

semi_join(df1, df2, by = "id") |>
  mutate(in_df2 = "Yes") |>
  left_join(df1, y = _) |>
  mutate(in_df2 = replace_na(in_df2, "No"))
```

Answer (score 0):

#### are you matching *all* values of ID, var1, and var2?

A lazy approach involves pasting columns together, finding a unique character to prevent coincidental hits. Here I use `.`.

```
a <- data.frame(n=1:26, y=letters)
b <- data.frame(n=26, y='z')

match(
  apply(a, 1, paste, collapse='.'),
  apply(a, 1, paste, collapse='.')
)
```

Similarly, you can use `interaction`:

```
match(interaction(a), interaction(b))
```

### are you asking to filter df1 to only the rows where ID occurs in df2?

Then do:

```
df1[df1$ID %in% df2$ID, ]
```